# i would like hover one element to affect other elements css

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

added a hover state on my main box element, i want it to turn grey and the text within to turn white

this is the main element: .blogcont

There are 2 other elements within it which are a h4 and another text div :.listing

i would like to change the font color of the h4 and the other div to white upon hover state on .blogcont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```css
.blogcont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  color: black
}
.blogcont:hover {
  background: grey;
}
.blogcont:hover h4,
.blogcont:hover .listing {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="blogcont">
  <h4>hellooo</h4>
  <div class="listing">listingggg</div>
</div>
```